# Geonodes how to turn off attribute box?

Tags: geometry-nodes

I am creating a tool and i want to get rid of these attribute boxes.
Does anyone know how to turn these off?

[image: attribute box]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The only way I found is a bit weird but plugging the input into a socket that doesn't support fields automatically disables using named attribute fields in the modifier interface. It works even if the other node is connected to nothing. If a socket is round, then it doesn't support fields :

[image]

It also doesn't have to be of the right type.

[image]

Here's a simple way to prevent a bunch of inputs from displaying the fields icon without cluttering too much the node tree :

[image]

Comment: Woow super thanks, very helpfull. I have spent some time to find a solution and you just did it. I wish there was a button for this.

Comment: I keep having to use the same sort of workaround to get a Viewer node to be of the right type, at the moment.

Comment: @RobinBetts Unless I'm mistaken on what you meant ? you can change the viewer type with CTRL + SHIFT + Left click on a socket with node wrangler

Comment: On a socket? Not a node? I'll have a look! Gawwd.. is it that simple.... Aaaargh! Thanks!

Comment: @RobinBetts hehe ! Although it might be that it's been added recently, I'm using 3.2 atm and both clicking on a node and an individual socket dynamically changes the view node input socket type :)

Answer (score 4):

in Blender 4.0 tick "Single Value" under the node input interface. It will only allow single value input.
[image]